# Using a unicode-math font that looks like computer modern roman

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, latin-modern, blackboard

I'm looking for a math font that works with the unicode-math package that looks just like computer modern roman. I found the latin modern roman font quite good, but they have a ℝ symbol which looks really ugly imo.

[image]

Is there a unicode math font that looks just like computer modern roman ? Or could I maybe replace the bbold symbols ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX Gyre Termes Math has blackboard bold letters similar to the `amsfonts` ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbb]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
$abc\mathbb{R}\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{N}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the result if XITS Math is used intead of Termes:

[image]

Just take your pick; you can experiment also with TeX Gyre Pagella Math or Asana Math.

Answer (score 3):

Uncomment the line to see that the P and the others should also be changed:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{LatinModernMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[range={"211D,%"2119,"211A
  }]{XITSMath}
\begin{document}

\Huge$\BbbP\BbbQ\BbbR $

\end{document}
```

[image]